# Внести загрузку резервов в отдельный запрос з фронт-енда

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, jquery-ui

Данные которые приходят с бекенда

```
{
  "data": [[{"id": 6, "name": "Card UAH", "reserve": "862857.94"}], [{"id": 4, "name": "Bitcoin", "reserve": "1.09075963"}], []],
  "error": null,
  "message": "Ok",
  "result": true
}
```

нужно сдлеать блоки с дивами с в них вносить значение которые передаються с бекенда

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.post("/ru/reserves", function(response, status){



    function tda(){
        var was = document.createElement("div");
        var ewe = $('<div>').addClass('reserve-item').text(123);

        console.log(ewe);
        return ewe
    };
    function myFunction() {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
    }

      var colLenght = $("<div>").addClass('col-sm-4').text(tda());
      var colLenght2 = $("<div>").addClass('col-sm-4').html(123);
      var colLenght3 = $("<div>").addClass('col-sm-4').html(132);
      $('#reserves2').find('.reserve-wrap').append([colLenght, colLenght2, colLenght3]);
  });

});
```

структура html

```
<div id="reserves2" class="exchange-reserve">
  <div class="container flychange-container">
    <div class="corner-left-top"></div>
    <div class="liner-for-corner-left-top"></div>
    <div class="corner-left-down"></div>
    <div class="liner-for-corner-left-down"></div>
    <div class="corner-right-top"></div>
    <div class="liner-for-corner-right-top"></div>
    <div class="corner-right-down"></div>
    <div class="liner-for-corner-right-down"></div>
    <div class="title">Резервы валют</div>
    <div class="reserve-wrap">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Вот то что приходит с бека нужно подставлять все значение которые передаються в array  а сейчас выходит что 1 значение каждого array генерирует

```
{"data":[[{"currency":980,"id":6,"name":"Card UAH","reserve":"100397.42"},{"currency":2000,"id":4,"name":"Bitcoin","reserve":"1.09965718"},{"currency":980,"id":9,"name":"WM test","reserve":"1000"},{"currency":980,"id":12,"name":"Test 4","reserve":"1000"},{"currency":980,"id":15,"name":"Test 7","reserve":"1000"},{"currency":2005,"id":19,"name":"Litecoin","reserve":"0.0476"},{"currency":840,"id":22,"name":"Card USD","reserve":"500"}],[{"currency":840,"id":2,"name":"Payeer","reserve":"4226.53"},{"currency":643,"id":5,"name":"Capitalist RUB","reserve":"21.45"},{"currency":980,"id":10,"name":"Test 2","reserve":"1000"},{"currency":980,"id":13,"name":"Test 5","reserve":"1000"},{"currency":840,"id":16,"name":"WEX USD","reserve":"1657.29"},{"currency":2001,"id":20,"name":"BitcoinCash","reserve":"0.00501"},{"currency":2002,"id":23,"name":"Ethereum","reserve":"0.042"}],[{"currency":643,"id":3,"name":"YandexMoney Personal","reserve":"1250070.59"},{"currency":980,"id":7,"name":"LiqPay UAH","reserve":"2.4"},{"currency":980,"id":11,"name":"Test 3","reserve":"1000"},{"currency":980,"id":14,"name":"Test 6","reserve":"1000"},{"currency":643,"id":18,"name":"QIWI RUB","reserve":"1003.5"},{"currency":2006,"id":21,"name":"Dash","reserve":"0.0195"}]],"error":null,"message":"Ok","result":true}
```

вот структура по html

```
<div class="reserve-wrap">


        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="reserve-info">
            <div class="icon"><img src=""></div>
            <div class="title">Card UAH</div>
            <div class="sum">100397.42</div>
          </div>
        </div>
</dv>
```

Comment: давненько в json'ом не связывался, по моемому там вместо $.post нужно $.getJSON

Comment: @SergeyArchipov post делает пост-запрос, getJSON - гет-запрос с дата-тайпом "json".

Comment: @SergeyArchipov по запросам все ок, мне с бека приходит все верно, мне нужно с помощью js или же jquery построить блоки следующим образом, 
что бы в один общий див допустим <div class="main-block"> добавлялись 3 дива с id name  и reserve и в каждый див передавались параметры которые приходят с бекенда

Comment: @СергійЧуйко напишите разметку которую хотите отрендерить

Comment: <div class="reserve-info">
   <div class="icon">
      <img src="">
    </div>
    <div class="title"</div>
    <div class="sum"></div>
</div>
@AGS17

Comment: @AGS17, все верно, совсем забыл)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добро пожаловать в 2018!

https://wesbos.com/template-strings-html/

```js
function renderReserve(data) {
  function renderReserveRow(rowData) {
    return `
      <div class="reserve-info">
        <div class="icon"><img src=""></div>
        <div class="title">${rowData.name}</div>
        <div class="sum">${rowData.reserve}</div>
      </div>`;
  }

  function renderReserveColumn(columnData) {
    return `
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        ${columnData.map(r =>renderReserveRow(r)).join('')}
      </div>`;
  }

  return data.data
    .filter(c => c[0]) // убираем пустые массивы
    .map(c => renderReserveColumn(c)) // генерим разметки каждых столбцов
    .join('');
}

document.querySelector('#reserves2 > .reserve-wrap').innerHTML = renderReserve({"data":[[{"currency":980,"id":6,"name":"Card UAH","reserve":"100397.42"},{"currency":2000,"id":4,"name":"Bitcoin","reserve":"1.09965718"},{"currency":980,"id":9,"name":"WM test","reserve":"1000"},{"currency":980,"id":12,"name":"Test 4","reserve":"1000"},{"currency":980,"id":15,"name":"Test 7","reserve":"1000"},{"currency":2005,"id":19,"name":"Litecoin","reserve":"0.0476"},{"currency":840,"id":22,"name":"Card USD","reserve":"500"}],[{"currency":840,"id":2,"name":"Payeer","reserve":"4226.53"},{"currency":643,"id":5,"name":"Capitalist RUB","reserve":"21.45"},{"currency":980,"id":10,"name":"Test 2","reserve":"1000"},{"currency":980,"id":13,"name":"Test 5","reserve":"1000"},{"currency":840,"id":16,"name":"WEX USD","reserve":"1657.29"},{"currency":2001,"id":20,"name":"BitcoinCash","reserve":"0.00501"},{"currency":2002,"id":23,"name":"Ethereum","reserve":"0.042"}],[{"currency":643,"id":3,"name":"YandexMoney Personal","reserve":"1250070.59"},{"currency":980,"id":7,"name":"LiqPay UAH","reserve":"2.4"},{"currency":980,"id":11,"name":"Test 3","reserve":"1000"},{"currency":980,"id":14,"name":"Test 6","reserve":"1000"},{"currency":643,"id":18,"name":"QIWI RUB","reserve":"1003.5"},{"currency":2006,"id":21,"name":"Dash","reserve":"0.0195"}]],"error":null,"message":"Ok","result":true});
```

```html
<div id="reserves2">
  <div class="reserve-wrap"></div>
</div>
```

Для более продвинутого рендеринга советую присмотреться к фреймворкам 
(например https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl)

Comment: не работает(
а что вот это за кавычки и для чего они нужны? http://prntscr.com/k48waf

Comment: + мне нужно обезательно выполнять вот этот код 
$.post("/ru/reserves", function(response, status){}
потому как даные с бекенда поступают в эту папку и от туда я вытягиваю данные и должен подставить их)

Comment: и у меня немного другая структура html указал выше

Comment: Серьезно? Скопируйте функицию `renderReserve()` и передавайте туда что пришло с сервера. Функция нагенерит вам html - вставляйте его куда вам надо

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: не хочте отрабатывать этот кусок кода http://prntscr.com/k499a8

Comment: ваш код работает, можете еще немного помочь, ваш код выводит только 1 значение с массива: а как мне вынести все значания? потому как с бека мне приходит 3 array которые имеют по 6 масовов http://prntscr.com/k4mkxm @AGS17

Comment: @СергійЧуйко Скиньте скрин текстом ([редактировать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/852088/edit)) и напишите там же html который должен получиться

Comment: сделал в вопросе @AGS17

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79969/discussion-between-ags17-and--).